# Converting Java byte to Perl

Tags: java, perl, encryption

Have a program written in Java that compresses then encrypts using cipher openssl aes.

I am writing a program in Perl that will decrypt then uncompress.

I am having problems with decrypting part and believe it is related to Java byte conversion for IV.

Note: I do not know anything about Java language.

Java:

```
static byte[] IV = new byte[] {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
```

Perl:

```
my $iv = pack('b128', 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15);
```

I have tried above and a few other combinations, but does not seem to be correct IV.

Please tell me how to do the conversion correctly.

Comment: Note that this is fine for testing, but in the field static IV's make little sense.

Answer (score 3):

You can read about `pack` in the [docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html).

`b` corresponds to a **bit string** in the context of `pack`, which probably isn't what you want. There is an example in [perlpacktut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html) that looks like this:

```
$byte = pack( 'B8', '10001100' ); # start with MSB
$byte = pack( 'b8', '00110001' ); # start with LSB
```

You might be able to use `c` which corresponds to **a signed char (8-bit) value**.

```
my $iv = pack('c16', 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15);
print unpack 'c16', $iv;
```

Which I think would be similar to this Java code:

```
import java.lang.Byte;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class ByteStuff{

     public static void main(String []args){

        byte[] IV = new byte[] {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(IV));
     }
}
```